User forced to reauthenticate after browser close - AppServiceAuthSession cookie has Expire/Max-Age as Session
I am using Azure container apps and its authentication feature. My use case is to provide users with an authenticated session which lasts as long as possible.
On a previous question I have written that the issue is EasyAuthConfig/login/cookieExpiration/timeToExpiration after which I have set it to 30 days and this seems to work fine, but only in the case when the user does not close the browser or if there are browser specific settings which retain tab data.
The issue seems quite obvious now, it is that the AppServiceAuthSession cookie, which is issued after authenticating, has an Expire/Max-Age property set to Session, which explains why the user needs to reauthenticate (the cookie is gone after browser close).
Is there a way to change the Expire/Max-Age property to something else? If not, is there any other way to not force the user to reauthenticate after a browser close, in my use case it is important that users do not reenter credentials so often?
I have set the EasyAuthConfig/login/cookieExpiration/timeToExpiration property on the container app to be 30 days, which is fine only if the user does not close the browser, or persists the session cookie in a different way.

If  this happens only when a user closes the browser, I think user has selected to clear all the cookies/storage data on closing the browser. Unfortunately, It'll depend only on the user how they want to use their system. If the user wants a good expereince, I think you can put a notice on the webpage to allow cookies for better UX

As far as I know Azure does not provide an explicit configuration to change the session cookie's Expires or Max-Age attribute directly through the Azure portal or Azure Container App settings.
So you need an workaround with code. Try the the following:
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next();

    if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var existingCookie = context.Request.Cookies["AppServiceAuthSession"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(existingCookie))
        {
            var options = new CookieOptions
            {
                Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(30), // Set expiration to 30 days
                HttpOnly = true,
                Secure = context.Request.IsHttps
            };
            context.Response.Cookies.Append("AppServiceAuthSession", existingCookie, options);
        }
    }
});


Unfortunately this will not work because the cookie gets handled by a sidecar authentication middleware that runs alongside my application (this is known as easyauth). Once the cookie is checked in the authentication store, headers are enriched so there is no authentication logic in my app which is running under container apps.
